# Adding a sub-form to a split form as both single form and datasheet

Tags: ms-access

I have a database of support tickets that each represent a single support project. Any single support project may have any number of emails related to it. I have a form that connects the two, and I like how it currently works as a nested datasheet: the main form is the tickets, and you can expand any ticket to show the email items attached to it within the same grid space.

What I want to add is a text box below the datasheet (ala split form) that shows the body text of the email that is selected, instead of the second datasheet list of emails in the bottom half of the form pictured. I have tried binding a single unrelated textbox and creating the subform as a split form, neither of which worked.

[image: ExampleForm]

***Is it possible to add a reference in a split form to some fields of a second table or query in datasheet form, and others in single-form form?*** (and obviously: how?)

---

The table of Emails is a linked table to an outlook mailitem folder, which means it doesn't and can't have an ID field, whether primary or foreign. The relationship is determined by a reference to the PK of the Support Project records inserted into the mailitem's subject. Creating a query that extracts this ID currently results in Access complaining that the expression is too complex (as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55093998/9513577)), and creating a query that filters the linked table by looking for the ID in the Subject is what's being used in the above example (as in `WHERE Subject LIKE "*Support Project [#]CS" & [ID] & " *"`)

Comment: This looks like you need a data entry form based on the ticket with a subform  for the emails and a sub-subform for the email text.  working on the solution

Comment: No, the records are created automatically by a vba module in Outlook whenever a new (without a "ticket ID" string in the subject) support request comes in. So I shouldn't need a data entry form, only the ability to change the priority and status fields of existing records.

Comment: later I'll add a comments table so that comments about tickets can be made at any point where the existing parameters aren't sufficient for some piece of information that is relevant, but as this is an extreme edge case, I'm getting the basic thing up and running first. Point of the view is just to be able to see tickets over time, and correspondence for each individual ticket.

Answer (score 0):

To change status and priority you still use a data entry form.  We are going to build a data entry form for a 1 to many relationship.  to get the text box to behave as you want wrap it in a subform targeted at the emails table and put that new subform in the footer of your current data entry form. The email section of your main data entry form should already be targeted at the email table as well.  So you have two subforms targeted at the emails table.  Start with an appropriate table structure like:
[image]

My form ended up looking like this, everything works as you would expect:

[image]

Email Text Form, record source is still the emails table. put this form in the footer for the email form, default view single form.

Email form: record source is emails put this form in footer for tickets form default view continuous.

Tickets form.  record source is tickets default view continuous.

Comment: This doesn't work because there is no ID field in the Emails table, and I can't add one (it's a linked table to outlook mailitems folder). However, it's given me the idea of making a query that works out what the ID *should* be (based on the subject string where it's added) and then adds it as a field rather than using it to filter on the query already... Trying that now.

Comment: Ugh. That might work, but it doesn't like how complicated it is to get the ID out of the Subject. I get "This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated. For example, a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements. Try simplifying the expression by assigning parts of the expression to variables." from my three fields: 
SELECT InStr(Subject,"Support Project #CS")+19 AS StartID,
InStr(StartID,Subject," ") AS EndID,
Val(Mid(Subject,StartID,EndID-StartID)) AS ID...
Do I need to ask a new question to figure out how to answer this one...?

Comment: Ok, so using the footer I was able to add a text box that reads the content field from the email table, but it does not display the same record selected in the rest of the form. It's materially different from your example in that I can't explicitly make the database structure as you have, as linked tables to email folders don't and can't have unique keys in the database. Or if they can, I've not found out how, despite asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54860470/9513577) to that effect.

Comment: a primary key of some type is essential so if the emails table doesn't have an equivalent how about virtually extending the emails table.  make emails2 with same columns + an ID

Comment: I'm not familiar with conversationid and outlook.  One thing that might help is create a new table with an emails fk and an email content variable.  you can catch all emails after the first with the new table.

Comment: How would I automatically change the records in emails2 to reflect those that exist in emails1? I'd love to do something like that if I knew how...

Comment: If you don't have access to the emails table you can still add variables too it by creating an emails2 table with a primary key and an email content variable.  this is like using a wrapper function to add new functionality to a piece of code you don't directly control.  for the initial email you can insert something generic like first contact into the email contact variable.  for the rest of the email you can put the actual email contact in.

Comment: What do you mean by an email content variable? It seems like you're suggesting I create a new table that has a primary key and then a reference to each record in the existing email table, but the only way I'm aware of for referencing records in another table is Foreign Key, and I can't add any fields to the existing email table at all, which has no guaranteed unique field.

Comment: extracting a primary key fixes all your problems and is much simpler than my idea.  The answer will work after you get a primary key.  my comments continue at the other question.