# ID Extracted from string not useable for connecting to bound form - "expression ... too complex"

Tags: sql, ms-access, relationship

I have a linked table to a Outlook Mailitem folder in my Access Database. This is handy in that it keeps itself constantly updated, but I can't add an extra field to relate these records to a parent table.

My workaround was to put an automatically generated/added ID String into the Subject so I could work from there. In order to make my form work the way I need it to, I'm trying to create a query that takes the fields I need from the linked table and adds a calculated field with the extracted ID so it can be referenced for relating records in the form.

The query works fine (I get all the records and their IDs extracted) but when I try to filter records from this query by the calculated field I get:

> This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated. For example, a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements. Try simplifying the expression by assigning parts of the expression to variables.

I tried separating the calculated field out into three fields so it's easier to read, hoping that would make it easier to evaluate for Access, but I still get the same error. My base query is currently:

```
SELECT InStr(Subject,"Support Project #CS")+19 AS StartID, 
       InStr(StartID,Subject," ") AS EndID, 
       Int(Mid(Subject,StartID,EndID-StartID)) AS ID, 
       ProjectEmails.Subject, 
       ProjectEmails.[From], 
       ProjectEmails.To, 
       ProjectEmails.Received, 
       ProjectEmails.Contents
FROM ProjectEmails
WHERE (((ProjectEmails.[Subject]) Like "*Support Project [#]CS*"));
```

I've tried to bind a subform to this query on qryProjectEmailWithID.ID = SupportProject.ID where the main form is bound to SupportProject, and I get the above error. I tried building a query that selects all records from that query where the ID = a given parameter and I still get the same error.

---

The working query that adds Support Project IDs would look like:

```
+----+--------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------+----------------------------------+
| ID |               Subject                |          To          |         From         |  Received  |             Contents             |
+----+--------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------+----------------------------------+
|  1 | RE: Support Project #CS1 ID Extra... | questions@so.com     | Isaac.Reefman@so.com | 2019-03-11 | Trying to work out how to add... |
|  1 | RE: Support Project #CS1 ID Extra... | isaac.reefman@so.com | questions@so.com     | 2019-03-11 | Thanks for your question. The... |
|  1 | RE: Support Project #CS1 ID Extra... | isaac.reefman@so.com | questions@so.com     | 2019-03-11 | You should use a different me... |
|  2 | RE: Support Project #CS2 IT issue... | support@domain.com   | someone@company.com  | 2019-02-21 | I really need some help with ... |
|  2 | RE: Support Project #CS2 IT issue... | someone@company.com  | support@domain.com   | 2019-02-21 | Thanks for your question. The... |
|  2 | RE: Support Project #CS2 IT issue... | someone@company.com  | support@domain.com   | 2019-02-21 | Have you tried turning it off... |
|  3 | RE: Support Project #CS3 email br... | support@domain.com   | someone@company.com  | 2019-02-12 | my email server is malfunccti... |
|  3 | RE: Support Project #CS3 email br... | someone@company.com  | support@domain.com   | 2019-02-12 | Thanks for your question. The... |
|  3 | RE: Support Project #CS3 email br... | someone@company.com  | support@domain.com   | 2019-02-13 | I've just re-started the nece... |
+----+--------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------+----------------------------------+
```

The view in question would populate a datasheet that looks the same with just the items whos ID matches  the ID of the current SupportProject record, updating when a new record is selected. A separate text box should show the full content of whichever record is selected in *that* grid, like this:

> Have you tried turning it off and on again?
>
> From: support@domain.com
>
> On: 21/02/2019
>
> Thanks for your question. The matter has been assigned to Support Project #CS2, and a support staff member will be in touch shortly to help you out.  As it is considered of medium priority, you should expect daily updates.
>
> Thanks,
>
> Support
>
> From: someone@company
>
> On: 21/02/2019
>
> I really need some help with my computer. It seems really slow and I can't do my work efficiently.

Neither of these things happens as when I try to use the calculated number to relate to the PK of the SupportProject table...

---

I don't know if this is a part of the problem, but whether I use `Int(Mid(Subject...` or `Val(Mid(Subject...` I still apparently get a Double, where the ID field (as an autoincrement ID) is a Long. I can't work out how to force it to return a Long, so I can't test whether that's the problem.

Comment: Edit question to provide sample data as well as desired output  - as text, not image.

Comment: @June7 Like that? Seems like noise to me, but if it means I'm more likely to get a good answer I'm happy to try it.

Comment: Please show us the filter.  Can you run the filter on the existing Outlook folder or does it fail with some sort of data problem?

Comment: Because it's a linked table to outlook I can't edit the fields in it, so the raw data is what's above (plus more fields I'm less interested in) minus the ID field that I get from an expression very similar to what's in [June7's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55095491/9513577). Multiple Email records go with each SupportProject record, and so far I've successfully added them to a form with `WHERE Subject LIKE "*Support Project [#]CS" & [ID] & " *"`. But I can't work as easily with them if they don't have IDs themselves...

Comment: Fix your table design and all your problems will be solved. You should never have to make any `Instr()` and other `Mid()` to retrieve IDs embedded in a string. You should have columns that store your 2 IDs as numbers.

Comment: @ThomasG if you know of a way to add a column to a linked table of outlook mailitems, then yes, I'd LOVE to add a PK *and* a FK(Support Project) to my email table! That would indeed make all my problems go away! Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to do this, and neither could any of the 30 people viewing [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54860470/9513577) over the last two weeks.

Comment: in vba use clng to cast to a long.  Perhaps adding an intermediate step will help.  try converting your working select query into a make table query to get around the error.  then continue from the new table.  The query designer has a make query tab.

Answer (score 0):

So that is output resulting from posted SQL? I really wanted raw data but close enough. If requirement is to extract number after `...CS`, calculate in query and save query:
`Val(Mid([Subject],InStr([Subject],"CS")+2))`

Then build another query to join first query to table.

```
SELECT qryProjectEmailWithID.*, SupportProject.tst
FROM qryProjectEmailWithID
INNER JOIN SupportProject ON qryProjectEmailWithID.ID = SupportProject.ID;
```

Filter criteria can be applied to either ID field.

A subform can display the related child records synchronized with SupportProject records on main form.

I tested the ID calc with your data and then with a link to my Inbox. No issue with query join.